# how to cache a data source contents?

Tags: asp.net

how to cache  data source contents?
suppose I'm retrieving some records from my sql server database and fill them in a data source or a data table.
How can I cache the data source or data table contents?

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCon.Open();
    string sq = "exec RetrieveLastVariableWorkerInfo @RealCode";
    SqlCom = new SqlCommand(sq, SqlCon);
    SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@RealCode", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = RealCode;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCom);
    da.Fill(dt1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net offers several APIs to store data.

The Cache object can be used to store any object. The API is pretty flexible.

```
Cache["MyObject"] = dt1;
Cache.Insert("MyObject", dt1)
```

This will put your data table into the system cache. You can place expiration times on the cache if the data goes stale or link it to an external dependency (such as SQL server or a file) so that changes in the external reference automatically invalide the cache.

It's also worth noting that ASP.Net will clear the cache automatically if memory becomes tight. Any data you place in the cache is available to all requests.

If the data is more specific to one user, you could place the data table into the user's Session object. The Session is generally linked to one user's browsing session by a unique ID. This way you can read several different data tables into memory without any conflict.

Comment: you are right about sessions, but sometimes when I store a data table with about 100000 records in session  I encounter with out of memory exception. I have this problem in my personal pc not in the server.

Comment: Would depend on the amount of memory available to the Framework. Whey do you need to retrieve 100K records? It might be better to actually load the data as you need it? Is the retrieval very slow?

Comment: it's because of paging in gridview, it needs all of the records to can page the gridview, if i don't use the paging in the gridview I should make the paging my self and read for example 10 by 10 records from database  and it will be slow in the last records.

Comment: Would the user really need to view all 100K records? Could you tune the performance on the retrieval of each page worth of records? Retrieving 10 or 20 records from a database should be *very* fast.

Comment: how do you retrieve 10 by 10 records from database, I'm using Row_Number() Over(order by tbl_requests.id) function. but it's slow in the last records because of 'order by'

Comment: If the query is as fast as it can be made, reading the data into memory is best option. Do you expect the data volumns to grow? This would be something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to use the Cache object provided by ASP.NET. This is shared globally across your application and any objects stored there are available to all page requests. You can specify the amount of time an object should stay in the cache (either and absolute time or with a sliding expiration) and define a dependency which will remove the cached object if it is triggered e.g. a Sql dependency will remove the object from the cache if a change is made to the table(s) where the data has come from.
[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) gives a good overview  of the subject, specifically the section on Caching API, Using the Object Cache.
You may also want to look at the [CacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx) (specifically [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks.aspx) in your case) object to refresh you cached items as changes occur in your database.
Things to be aware of are the size of the objects your are storing, how long they are stored for before they are outdated and should be removed from the cache and if there should be any external triggers which should remove them from the cache.

Comment: could you explain more about it? I think the cache object is shared for every user, isn't it?